# Why flutter doesn't pass a new context to predefined widgets? (thus required a Builder widget in some .of() usages)

Tags: flutter

I'm checking the official [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html) and the official YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXNOkIuSYuA) for Builder widget.

In the docs the following example fails

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Fails because Scaffold.of() doesn't find anything
          // above this widget's context.
          print(Scaffold.of(context).hasAppBar);
        },
        child: const Text('hasAppBar'),
      )
    ),
  );
}
```

I know why this particular example fails, since the context used in `print(Scaffold.of(context).hasAppBar);` doesn't contain the Scaffold.

The question is why flutter doesn't pass automatically a new context for the `Center` or `TextButton` widgets as it does with user-defined classes?

And can't we use something like `print(this.hasAppBar);`

Comment: "The question is why flutter doesn't pass automatically a new context for the Center" how flutter could do that? the only way is by providing some callback methods, but would you like to use `child: (ctx) => ...` everywhere?

Comment: I'm convinced, good insight.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very interesting question, I'll try to answer based on my experience and perspective.

It is because predefined widgets like `Center` and `TextButton` are not in charge of maintaining the hierarchy of widgets, Flutter does not transmit a new context to them. Instead, it falls on the parent widget in the widget tree to give its child widgets the proper context.

In the example you gave, the `Scaffold` widget is not present in the `Center` widget's context, which is the `BuildContext` that is sent to the `TextButton` widget. Since it can't locate the closest `Scaffold` widget in the widget tree, calling `Scaffold.of(context)` will fail.

Well, there is a workaround for this, You can use the `Builder` widget, a built-in widget that generates a fresh `BuildContext` for its child widget, to resolve this problem. Calling `Scaffold.of(context)` will yield the appropriate Scaffold widget since this new `BuildContext` contains the `Scaffold` widget as one of its ancestors.

And about the second query, the `Scaffold` widget and `TextButton` widget are not in the same class, thus you cannot use `this` to access Scaffold widget properties from within the `TextButton` widget `.this` refers to the active instance of the class; in this case, the `TextButton` widget and the `Scaffold` widget have different classes. So you are forced to use `Scaffold.of(context)` with the relevant `BuildContext` to gain access to the scaffold widget's properties.

Comment: thanks, I'm aware of the workaround, I was just curious why the different behavior, regarding the second question, I'm also aware they're different classes, however I was searching for something to reference the "parent widget" which is the scaffold in this case.
thanks

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't answer my question, a comment on the question answered the first question.